# How to define a norm on a vector space?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Assume that $\pi:(V_1,||.||_1)\to V_2$ is a surjective linear map from a normed vector space into a vector space. How to find a norm $||.||_2$ on $V_2$ using this map?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $\pi : V_1 \to V_2$ is a linear surjection, $\bar{\pi}: V_1/\ker \pi \to V_2$ (defined by $\bar{\pi}(x+\ker \pi) = \pi(x)$) will be a bijection. Now how can you use $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$ to define a norm on $V_1/\ker \pi$?

Comment: In this case one can define a norm $||.||$ on $V_1/ker \pi$ as $||x+ker \pi||=||x||_1$ and then easily define a norm $||.||_2$ on $V_2$ as $||w||_2=||\pi(x+ker \pi)||_2=||x||_1$.

Comment: @Majid Nope, that won't work. Your norm isn't well defined. Suppose $x,y \in V_1$ with $x -y \in \ker \pi$. Then $x+ \ker \pi = y + \ker \pi$ but it isn't necessarily true that $\lVert x \rVert_1 = \lVert y \rVert_1$.

Comment: @Demophilis yes you are right. what about this: Let $\bar x=x+ker \pi$. Then $|| \bar x||=inf \{||x||_1 : \bar x=x+ker\pi\}$?

Comment: @Majid That is indeed a norm, which isn't too hard to verify.

Comment: Now my question is that why people easily do not use this solution? Why they bother themselves defining the unit balls on the vector spaces and then defining the norm using the unit ball on $V_2$?
It does not mean that something must be wrong with this way?

Comment: @Majid I don't really know what method you're talking about so I can't judge whether that's a better method, but I would guess the methods to be essentially the same. Maybe you should ask about this in another question?

Comment: Yes, sounds a good advice!